# implement a rails before_filter in ruby without rails

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-1.9.3, before-filter

I am using g a logger in all of my classes. 
I want each msg to begin with class name and method name like so:

```
Class_name::Method_name
```

this is what i'm doing now :

```
class FOO

 def initialize
 end

 def bar
   msg_prefix = "#{self.class}::#{__method__}"
   ... some code ...
   @logeer = "#{msg_prefix} msg ..."
 end

 def bar2
   msg_prefix = "#{self.class}::#{__method__}"
   ... some code 2 ...
   @logeer = "#{msg_prefix} msg2 ..."
 end

end
```

i want to use a before_filter like in rails to prevent duplicity, 
I am using `sinatra` but the classes are plain old `ruby 1.9.3` classes

ideas??

Comment: you can use activerecord with sinatra https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a callback on any method being created with [Module#method_added](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-method_added), alias the old method, then define a new method that calls the before_filter method first. Here's my (extremely) rough first concept:

```
module Filter
  def before_filter name
    @@filter = name
  end

  def method_added name
    return if @filtering # Don't add filters to original_ methods
    return if @@filter == name # Don't filter filters
    return if name == :initialize

    @filtering = true

    alias_method :"original_#{name}", name
    define_method name do |*args|
      self.send @@filter, name
      self.send :"original_#{name}", *args
    end
    @filtering = false
  end
end

class FilterTest
  extend Filter
  before_filter :prepare_logs

  def baz
    puts "#{@msg_prefix} message goes here"
  end

  def prepare_logs name
    @msg_prefix = "#{self.class}::#{name}"
  end
end

ft = FilterTest.new
ft.baz
```

By using `__method__` like you were in `create_prefix`, you'll get the name of the filter method, not the original method, so you have to pass the method name in. There might be other solutions to make that a bit cleaner.

Comment: thanks zaius, this indeed did the trick, but I have implemented it in the super class, and it worked for 1. the super class itself, 2. it's child, 3. for it's grandsons, it gave me a `Uncaught exception: stack level too deep` I wonder why..

Comment: Well.. it's kind of a hacky solution, so that doesn't surprise me. Paste your code and the error message up on gist or something and I can tell you why it's breaking.

Comment: sure, here is it. the instances are at the end. [gist](https://gist.github.com/ohadpartuck/5070783)

Comment: Oh, ok. It's happening because the initialize method gets defined twice. Added in a hack for it. Again, not pretty, but hopefully it's enough.

Comment: How could I do it in order to support filters without params, i.e. prepare_logs without the "name" argument ? Thx

Comment: And how could I do it for only some of the methods, not all of them, kind of only: [methods] or except: [methods] ? Thanks for your suggestions! :-)

Comment: For the first, use a constant as a name, or make the name an optional parameter. For the second, this code would need a bit of work - it doesn't really support multiple filters due to globals.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ActiveModel::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html) to get `before_filter`-like behaviour in plain Ruby classes (though perhaps in your case it's overkill for just executing one line):

```
require 'active_model'

class FOO
  extend ActiveModel::Callbacks

  define_model_callbacks :baz, only: :before

  before_baz :create_prefix

  def initialize
  end

  def bar
    run_callbacks :baz do
      ... some code ...
      @logeer = "#{@msg_prefix} msg ..."
    end
  end

  def bar2
    run_callbacks :baz do
      ... some code 2 ...
      @logeer = "#{@msg_prefix} msg2 ..."
    end
  end

  private

    def create_prefix
      @msg_prefix = "#{self.class}::#{__method__}"
    end
end
```

Comment: hi paul, thanks for the reponse, but i'm looking a way to use it the exact way rails use, one line `before_filter :do_prefix_msg` to run automatically before each function (unless told differently)

Comment: I think that using `ActiveModel::Callbacks` is the easiest way to get the exact effect you want without having to re-implement the fair amount of code that's behind [Rails' callbacks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.12/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb).  I had this same issue a while ago with one of my own projects, and couldn't find any solution better than `ActiveModel::Callbacks`.  But, in hope that there is some other way that someone else knows, I'll +1 the question.