# before_filter like functionality in lib class

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a class in the lib directory of my rails app, where the methods are all called on the class. Before each of these methods, I want to run a bit of code that is common to all of them. I've looked around and found a couple of ways, but they seem to be related to instance methods only instead of class methods.

My class looks a little like this :

```
class Push

    def self.user_checked_in(user, trip)
        ...
    end

    ... Other methods ...

end
```

What I want is to have something like

```
before_filter :method
```

Just like in controllers. What's the best approach for this, or would it be possible to simply include the responsible code from controllers?

Comment: check this out, whether it meet your need?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034125/implement-a-rails-before-filter-in-ruby-without-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like cluttering my controllers with unnecessary methods. In your case, I think the cleanest way would be to use a decorator. [This post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/14825364877/evaluating-alternative-decorator-implementations-in) covers some decorators in Ruby and is pretty popular. I personally like [this decorator gem](https://github.com/michaelfairley/method_decorators). Then your methods would look like this:

```
class Push
    +MyDecorator
    def self.user_checked_in(user, trip)
        ...
    end
end
```

If you want to do this for every single method, you could override `method_added` yourself, but I'd suggest going with decorators unless you have a lot of methods: it's more obvious, and it's easier to write methods where you don't want that bit of code called.

Comment: Works perfectly. nice gem :) I do have a fair few methods to use this on, but the `method_added` technique feels a little hacky, creating an alias. I'll use this for now I think, thanks :)